# Filter active tasks, completed tasks, and all tasks in a to Do List with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I am having some difficulty filtering through a list of tasks in To Do List project.
I use an object to store the core properties of each task created like the id, content, completed, and date.
The filter should occurs after the user selects an option in a drop down menu.
I use an Event Listener to catch the id of the option selected, but I don't know what to do with that Id. For example, when the user selects the option 'completed' the app should only display the completed task, or the tasks that have a property of 'completed:true'.
I also want to filter the list in a fancy way such as make tasks fade out when filtering.

URL: https://alonzocarlos95.github.io/WDD-330/

```
//html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!--ClockPicker libraries-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://weareoutman.github.io/clockpicker/dist/jquery-clockpicker.min.css"></link>
    <!-- <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Moment JS library CDN -->
    <!-- <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.25.1/moment.min.js"></script> -->
    <!--Material Icons and Fonts-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,200;1,100&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--Small view-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/small.css" media="screen">

    <title>Document</title>
  
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><span class="material-icons">done</span></li>
                <li class="drop-down" ><div class="dropdown"><button class="dropbtn" onclick="showModal()">All Lists<span class="material-icons" style="vertical-align: middle;">arrow_drop_down</span></button><div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content"><span id="select1">All Lists</span><span  id="select2">Active</span><span  id="select3">Completed</span></div></div></li>
                <li><span class="label_list">BYU-Idaho To do List</span></li>
                <li><span class="material-icons">search</span></li>
                <li><img src="images/b2-removebg-preview.png" alt="logo"></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
        <div class="notes">
        <img id="no_tasks" src="images/palms-300x220.png" alt="No tasks">
    </div>
    <div class="main_list" id="main_list">
        <ul id="parentList">

        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="new_task_container" id="container_schedule">
    <div class="new_task" id="new_todo">
        <label>What is to be done?</label>
        <div class="new_input">
        <input type="text" name="todo" id="todo" placeholder="Enter task here">
        <span class="material-icons">keyboard_voice</span>
        </div>
        <label>Due Date</label>
        <input type="date" id="date" name="date" placeholder="Date not set">
    </div>
    <div class="new_task_group2">
        <div class="new_time" id="new_time_container">
        <input type="text" name="time" id="time" placeholder="Time not set(all day)">
        <span class="material-icons">schedule</span>
        <!-- <input type="checkbox" style="display: none;"> -->
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </main>
    <div class="add_task">
        <button id="add" class="bounce">+</button>
        </div>
        <script src="https://weareoutman.github.io/clockpicker/dist/jquery-clockpicker.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/todo.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
//Javacript

let toDoList = [];

let options = {weekday:'long', year:'numeric', month:'long', day:'numeric'};
let indicador = 0;
let list_container = document.getElementById('main_list');
document.getElementById('container_schedule').style.display = 'none';
const chosenDate = document.getElementById("date");
const time = document.getElementById('new_time_container');
let ulTasks = document.getElementById('parentList');
time.style.display = 'none';

document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.getElementById('container_schedule').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('add').innerHTML = '<span class="material-icons">done</span>';  
    let inputNewTask = document.getElementById("todo");
    let valInputNewTask = inputNewTask.value;
    let valInputNewTask2 = inputNewTask.value;
    let dateSet = document.getElementById('date').value;

    if(indicador === 0){
        indicador = 1;
        list_container.style.display = "none";
        
    }else {
           if(!isBlank(valInputNewTask)){ //Valida si el valor del input no es null o undefined o whitespace
            indicador = 0;
            inputNewTask.value = "";
            inputNewTask.focus();
            let newDateSet = valDate(dateSet);
            taskCreated();
            manageTask(valInputNewTask2,newDateSet);
            
            }
            else {
                alert("Enter task at first.");
            }
        
    }
} );
document.getElementById('date').addEventListener('change',() => {
    // alert("New date");
    time.style.display = 'flex';
});




 function taskCreated(){
    document.getElementById('container_schedule').style.display = 'none';
    // debugger;
    if(document.getElementsByClassName('notes').length >= 1){
        document.getElementsByClassName('notes')[0].remove();
    }
    document.getElementById('add').textContent = '+';
 }




/*Clock picker functionality*/
$("input[name=time]").clockpicker({       
    placement: 'bottom',
    align: 'left',
    autoclose: true,
    default: 'now',
    donetext: "Select",
    init: function() { 
                              console.log("colorpicker initiated");
                          },
                          beforeShow: function() {
                              console.log("before show");
                          },
                          afterShow: function() {
                              console.log("after show");
                          },
                          beforeHide: function() {
                              console.log("before hide");
                          },
                          afterHide: function() {
                              console.log("after hide");
                          },
                          beforeHourSelect: function() {
                              console.log("before hour selected");
                          },
                          afterHourSelect: function() {
                              console.log("after hour selected");
                          },
                          beforeDone: function() {
                              console.log("before done");
                          },
                          afterDone: function() {
                              console.log("after done");
                          }
  });
  

  function isBlank(str) {
    //debugger;
    return (!str || /^\s*$/.test(str));
}

function valDate(dateToDo){
    // debugger;
    if(dateToDo === null || dateToDo === ''){
        dateToDo = "No date";
        return dateToDo;
    }
    else {
        dateToDo = new Date(dateToDo);
        dateToDo.setDate(dateToDo.getDate()+1);
        // testDate = new Date(Date.UTC(dateToDo));
        dateToDo = dateToDo.toLocaleString('en-US',options);
        return dateToDo;
    }
}

function manageTask(getTask,dateSet){
    const todo = {
        id: Date.now(),
        content: getTask,
        completed: false,
        date: dateSet
    }
    toDoList.push(todo);
    addToLocalStorage(toDoList);
    // storeData(todo);
}


function addToLocalStorage(toDoList){
    // debugger;
    localStorage.setItem('toDoList',JSON.stringify(toDoList));

    renderTodos(toDoList);
}



function renderTodos(toDoList){
    // debugger;
    ulTasks.innerHTML = '';
    toDoList.forEach(function(valInputNewTask2,index){
        console.log(index);
        const checked = toDoList.completed ? 'checked': null;
        let currentTasks = document.createElement('li');
        currentTasks.id = valInputNewTask2.id;
        currentTasks.setAttribute('style','display:flex;background-color:#519872;width:100%;border-radius:7px;margin:0 0 10px 0;padding:6px 4px 6px 4px;min-height:3em;box-shadow: rgba(14, 30, 37, 0.12) 0px 2px 4px 0px, rgba(14, 30, 37, 0.32) 0px 2px 16px 0px;');
        
      

        currentTasks.innerHTML = '<input id='+index+' type = "checkbox"  class="checkInactive"><div style="display:flex;flex-direction:column;flex-grow:2;"><span style="margin-left:2em;">'+valInputNewTask2.content+'</span><span style="margin-left:2em;color:#17301C;">'+valInputNewTask2.date+'</span></div><div class="clear"><span class="material-icons">clear</span></div>';
        
        if(valInputNewTask2.completed === true){
            currentTasks.classList.add('checkActive');
            currentTasks.firstChild.checked = true;
        }  
        
        document.getElementById('parentList').appendChild(currentTasks);
        });
    list_container.style.display = "block";
}

function getFromLocalStorage(){
    const getReference = localStorage.getItem('toDoList');
    if(getReference){
        document.querySelector('.notes').style.display = 'none';
        toDoList = JSON.parse(getReference);
        renderTodos(toDoList);
    }
}


function showModal(){
    document.getElementById('myDropdown').classList.toggle('show');
}


getFromLocalStorage();


function toggle(id){
    toDoList.forEach(function(item){
        if(item.id == id){
            item.completed = !item.completed;
        }
    });
    addToLocalStorage(toDoList);
}

function deleteToDo(id){
    debugger
    // alert(id);
    toDoList = toDoList.filter(function(getTask){
        return getTask.id != id;
    });
    addToLocalStorage(toDoList);
}
debugger;
ulTasks.addEventListener('click',function(event){
    debugger;
    if(event.target.type === 'checkbox'){
        toggle(event.target.parentElement.getAttribute('id'));
    }
    if(event.target.parentElement.classList.contains('clear')){
        debugger;
        deleteToDo(event.target.parentElement.parentElement.getAttribute('id'));
    }
});





//Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside it
window.onclick = function(e) {
    if (!e.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var myDropdown = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
      if (myDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        myDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  } 




//Drop down Events
document.getElementById("myDropdown").addEventListener('click',function(event){
    debugger;
    if(event.target.localName === 'span'){
        alert(event.target.id);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the animations but at least for the filtering:

1. Ideally you should be using the select html element to create a dropdown menu and use the value attribute of the option elements to perform actions when an option is selected. Read more here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp
2. In your case, we can use the text inside the span tag, instead of the id to see which option was selected and render the todos based on the selected option.
3. We can then use the JS ES6 array function `.filter(item => condition)`, which loops over the items in the array and returns a new array with all the items that match the provided condition.

```js
document.getElementById('myDropdown').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    if (e.target.localName === 'span'){
        let selectedOption = e.target.innerText;

        if(selectedOption === 'All Tasks')
            renderToDos(toDoList); // render everything
 
        else if(selectedOption === 'Active'){
            let activeToDos = toDoList.filter(todo => todo.completed === false);
            renderToDos(activeToDos); // only render the todos which have not been completed
        }

        else if(selectedOption === 'Completed'){
            let completedToDos = toDoList.filter(todo => todo.completed === true);
            renderToDos(completedToDos); // only render the todos which have not been completed
        }
    }
});
```